# PHP Extract from the string

Tags: php, regex

I am new to php and need to extract "url" from following string

href=\"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gYDSNteP_60\">Fat, me? I'm just horizontally challenged"

Url length is vary for different URL's

Any help.

Thanks

Comment: Sorry edited my text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this

```
$string ="href=\"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gYDSNteP_60\">Fat, me? I'm just horizontally challenged";
$regex = '/https?\:\/\/[^\" ]+/i';
preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

This will return the URL as its only match:

```
/(?<=href=").+?(?=")/i
```

Answer (score 0):

```
href.*\/\/(.*?)\\
```

You can use this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/pP3pN1/24

Answer (score 0):

Use regexp with [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

```
href=\\(.*)>
```